# node/express - How to render user input to a page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am trying to render some text using node/express. 
I have a html file contains a form.

search.ejs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var userInput;
    $("#submit-button-id").click(function(){
        userInput = $1_11_1("#userInput").val();
        $.get("http://localhost:3000/searching", {
            userInput: userInput
        }, function(){});
    });
});
```

app.js

```
app.get('/searching', function(req, res){
    var userInput = req.query.userInput;

    /** I am able to get the userInput (the code above works) */

    res.send(userInput);

    /** I want to render the userInput (for instance, on localhost:3000/results) */
});
```

Any help/links would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app.js, you are sending the userInput information back to search.ejs. this is the location:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var userInput;
    $("#submit-button-id").click(function(){
        userInput = $1_11_1("#userInput").val();
        $.get("http://localhost:3000/searching", {
            userInput: userInput
        }, function(){***User data can be used here***});
    });
});
```

So the following code would work to render your raw data into a div on your html page called render-div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var userInput;
    $("#submit-button-id").click(function(){
        userInput = $1_11_1("#userInput").val();
        $.get("http://localhost:3000/searching", {
            userInput: userInput
        }, function(userInputData){
            $('.render-div).append(userInputData);

        });
    });
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) you have the response as a parameter in your callback, so you should try something like this:

```
$.get("http://localhost:3000/searching", {userInput: userInput},
    function(response){
      alert(response);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EJS you can do it like this:

First, in your results.ejs file

```
<div id="displayResult"><h2><%= result %></h2></div>
```

Then, in your app.js

```
app.get('/searching', function(req, res){
var userInput = req.query.userInput;
res.render('results.ejs',{result:userInput});
});
```